# If $X$ is a vector space endowed with a metric that is NOT norm induced and If $x_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y$, then $x_n+y_n\to x+y$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, hilbert-spaces

> Let $X$ be a real or complex vector space endowed with a metric $d$ which is not induced by a norm, that is there exist no norm $\| \cdot \|$ on $X$ such that $d(x,y)=\| x-y \|$. Prove or disprove:
>
> (a) If $x_n\to x$ and $\lambda_n\to \lambda$ ($\lambda_n,\lambda$ are scalars), then $\lambda_n x_n \to \lambda x$.
>
> (b) If $x_n\to x$ and $y_n\to y$, then $x_n+y_n\to x+y$.

This is throwing me off just because the vector space is endowed with a metric that is not norm induced, and I am not sure what all that implies. With that said, I think I may be doing this problem naively. Anyway, here are my solutions:

(a) Let $y\in X$ be fixed. Then, by the triangle inequality,
$$d(\lambda_nx_n,y) \leq d(\lambda_nx_n,\lambda x) + d(\lambda x, y),$$
similarly,
$$d(\lambda x,y)\leq d(\lambda x,\lambda_n x_n) + d(\lambda_n x_n , y),$$
which implies that
$$d(\lambda x,y) - d(\lambda_n x_n , y) \leq d(\lambda x,\lambda_n x_n),$$
so that as $n\to\infty$ we have $\lambda_n x_n \to \lambda x$.

(b) We may establish an upper bound via the triangle inequality, so that
$$
d(x_{n},y_{n}) \leq d(x_{n},x) + d(x,y) + d(y,y_{n}).
$$
Again for a lower bound, we use the triangle inequality:
$$
d(x,y) \leq d(x_{n},x) + d(x_{n},y_{n}) + d(y_{n},y);
$$
hence we have that,
$$
d(x,y) - d(x_{n},x) - d(y_{n},y) \leq d(x_{n},y_{n}).
$$
Now as $n \to \infty$ we have
$$
d(x_{n},y_{n}) \to d(x,y).
$$

Comment: We cannot expect that vector-space operations are continuous if the underlying topology need not be compatible with them. For instance, consider the lexicographic distance on $\mathbb{R}^2$.